# How to call particular stored procedure in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, execute

I have procedure into package of oracle that signature is:

```
PROCEDURE CourseGroupCost(cur              OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                            trainingOrg      IN VARCHAR)
```

How to call this procedure from oracle command or other hand what is syntax to call this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus:

```
variable c refcursor;
execute package_name.CourseGroupCost(:c, 'trainingOrg value');
print c;
```